# How to List all Sidebars in a Metabox

Tags: metabox, sidebar, list

I'm trying to add a metabox to every page that is a drop down list of all registered sidebars that is then saved in a custom field.

I'm using this [metabox class](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress)

I've gotten as far as this:

```
// get registered Sidebars
$sidebars = $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'];
foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ) { 
   $sidebar_options[$sidebar['name']] = $sidebar['name'];
}
```

Then I call the $sidebars variable in my metabox declaration like so:

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id'         => 'page_metabox',
    'title'      => 'Page Custom Fields',
    'pages'      => array( 'page', ), // Post type
    'context'    => 'normal',
    'priority'   => 'high',
    'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Page Sidebar',
            'desc' => 'Choose the Sidebar to show on this page.',
            'id'   => /*$prefix .*/ 'erh_page_sidebar',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => $sidebar_options,  

        )

    ) 

);
```

This is the result of $sidebar_options:

```
$sidebar_options = array (
 'Header Sidebar' => 'Header Sidebar',
 'Main Sidebar' => 'Main Sidebar',
 'News Sidebar' => 'News Sidebar',
 'Home Panel 1' => 'Home Panel 1',
 'Home Panel 2' => 'Home Panel 2',
 'Home Panel 3' => 'Home Panel 3',
 'Footer 1 Sidebar' => 'Footer 1 Sidebar',
 'Footer 2 Sidebar' => 'Footer 2 Sidebar',
 'Footer 3 Sidebar' => 'Footer 3 Sidebar',
 'Footer 4 Sidebar' => 'Footer 4 Sidebar',
 'Footer 5 Sidebar' => 'Footer 5 Sidebar',
 'Footer 6 Sidebar' => 'Footer 6 Sidebar',
 'Right Sidebar 1' => 'Right Sidebar 1',
 'Staff login Sidebar' => 'Staff login Sidebar',
 'Staff Sidebar' => 'Staff Sidebar',
 'Careers Sidebar' => 'Careers Sidebar',
 'Care Providers Sidebar' => 'Care Providers Sidebar',
  )
```

my problem is that this metabox class wants the drop down options to be in this form and I don't know how to do that:

```
array( 'name' => 'Sidebar 1', 'value' => 'Right Sidebar 1', ),
array( 'name' => 'Sidebar 2', 'value' => 'Right Sidebar 2', ),
array( 'name' => 'Sidebar 3', 'value' => 'Right Sidebar 3', ),
```

Any help is much appreciated :-)

Comment: the above results in a single dimensional array where I think I need a multi dimensional array, but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $sidebar_options = array();
    $sidebars = $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'];

    foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ){
        $sidebar_options[] = array(
            'name'  => $sidebar['name'],
            'value' => $sidebar['id']
        );
    }
?>
```

This prints out( with my registered sidebars ):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Language Menu
            [value] => sidebar-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Primary Sidebar
            [value] => primary-sidebar
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Secondary Sidebar
            [value] => secondary-sidebar
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Footer left box
            [value] => footer_box_left
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Footer middle box
            [value] => footer_box_middle
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Footer right box
            [value] => footer_box_right
        )

)
```

In a select tag this becomes:

```
<html>
    <select>
        <?php foreach( $sidebar_options as $option ){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option['value']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!