# How do you List all Sidebars in a Metabox

Tags: metabox, sidebar, list

I know this question has been answered many times before, including [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107542/how-to-list-all-sidebars-in-a-metabox/110822#110822) where i came from so it'll probably be real simple.

I've registered my sidebars as normal

```
function wmw_sidebars() {
    // Register default widgetized areas
    $sidebars = array(
        'primary' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Primary Widget Area', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'desc' => __( 'The primary widget area', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN )
        ),
        'home' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Homepage Widget Area', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'desc' => __( 'The homepage widget area', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN )
        ),
    );

    foreach ( $sidebars as $type => $sidebar ){
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => $sidebar['name'],
            'id'=> $type,
            'description' => $sidebar['desc'],
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle"><span>',
            'after_title' => '</span></h4>',
        ));
    }
}
```

I'm using the same CMB [Metabox Class](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) as fshequin and have the metaboxes showing up in in my posts and pages.

```
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'WMW_page_layout_meta',
    'title' => __( 'Page Layout Options', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
    'pages' => get_post_types(),
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'default',
    'show_names' => false, // Show field names on the left
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Page Layout', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'desc' => __( 'You can choose between a left, right, or no sidebar layout for your page.', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'id' => '_layout',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                array('name' => 'Full Width (No Sidebar)', 'value' => 'full_width', ),
                array('name' => 'Sidebar on Left, Content on Right', 'value' => 'left_sidebar', ),
                array('name' => 'Sidebar on Right, Content on Left', 'value' => 'right_sidebar',)
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Page Sidebar', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'desc' => __( 'Choose the Sidebar to show on this page.', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'id'   => '_page_sidebar',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => $sidebar_options
        )
    )
);
```

But for whatever the reason I cannot seem to get the select options to show.

I Placed the array in the same functions file as registering the sidebars but not in a function.

```
$sidebars = $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'];

foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ){
    $sidebar_options[] = array(
        'name'  => $sidebar['name'],
        'value' => $sidebar['id']
    );
}
$sidebar_options = array();
```

Whatever I try, it is not happening, I changed the variable names to avoid conflict with sidebar register array but no dice.

Any help would be MUCH APPRECIATED!

------------------------ EDITED ---------------------------------------

Ok I broke it down and went to test each part of it.

```
$sidebar_ops = array(); 
$sidebar_ops[] = array(
    'name' => __( 'Page Sidebar 1', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
    'value' => 'sidebar_1',
    );
$sidebar_ops[] = array(
    'name' => __( 'Page Sidebar 2', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
    'value' => 'sidebar_2',
    );

  //$GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars']
  $sidebar_options = array();
  foreach ( $sidebar_ops as $sidebar_op ){
    $sidebar_options[] = array(
        'name'  => $sidebar_op['name'],
        'value' => $sidebar_op['id']
    );
  }
```

I compiled a bogus array and then used the foreach to test that.

The problem appears to be with `$GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars']` and using that array. What the proper way to call this?

Comment: Are you putting `$sidebar options = array();` after the foreach loop or is it a typo? If you leave it in that position its value will be set empty.

Comment: It doesn't work when its before it either

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a function like this:

```
        <?php

           /* Other stuff */

            function sidebarOptions(){
              $sidebars = $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'];
              $sidebar_options = array();
              foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ){
                $sidebar_options[] = array(
                    'name'  => $sidebar['name'],
                    'value' => $sidebar['id']
                );
              }
              return $sidebar_options;
            }

           /* Other stuff */

/*
 * Trying to print the result to check if it is what expect us
 * echo '<pre>';
 * print_r( sidebarOptions() );
 * echo '</pre>';
 */         
           $meta_boxes[] = array(
            'id' => 'WMW_page_layout_meta',
            'title' => __( 'Page Layout Options', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'pages' => get_post_types(),
            'context' => 'side',
            'priority' => 'default',
            'show_names' => false, // Show field names on the left
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => __( 'Page Layout', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
                    'desc' => __( 'You can choose between a left, right, or no sidebar layout for your page.', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
                    'id' => '_layout',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' => array(
                        array('name' => 'Full Width (No Sidebar)', 'value' => 'full_width', ),
                        array('name' => 'Sidebar on Left, Content on Right', 'value' => 'left_sidebar', ),
                        array('name' => 'Sidebar on Right, Content on Left', 'value' => 'right_sidebar',)
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => __( 'Page Sidebar', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
                    'desc' => __( 'Choose the Sidebar to show on this page.', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
                    'id'   => '_page_sidebar',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' => sidebarOptions()
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: So that sort of worked, I put in the function and when to test it, which returned 
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Primary Widget Area
            [value] => primary
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Homepage Widget Area
            [value] => home
        )

)`

Which is what I want but call the function in the meta box code did not work, still absolute blank.

Also when i attempted to print $sidebar_options that the function returns, nothing happened

Comment: what do you see if you "firebug" the select tag?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary tbh. Take a look at my edit, what do think? I just cant seem to get it to call `$GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars']`

Comment: try `global $wp_registered_sidebars;` that effort.. : )

Comment: Thanks.

Where am I going wrong

`global $wp_registered_sidebars;

  /*$sidebar_ops = array(); 
  $sidebar_ops[] = array(
   'name' => __( 'Page Sidebar 1', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
   'value' => 'sidebar_1',
   );
  $sidebar_ops[] = array(
   'name' => __( 'Page Sidebar 2', WMW_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
   'value' => 'sidebar_2',
   );*/
  
     
    $sidebar_options = array();
    foreach ($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar_op ){
   $sidebar_options[] = array(
    'name'  => $sidebar_op['name'],
    'value' => $sidebar_op['id']
   );
    }`

I placed it right before I call the metabox

Comment: your code seems ok, i've tested it and it works, i've used both: `$GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars']` and `global $wp_registered_sidebars;`

Comment: i can't see the call to `wmw_sidebars()` function, inside which there's the `register_sidebar` call

Comment: I call that in the part of my functions file where i define all my actions. It works and its registering my sidebars but is it conflicting?

Comment: which hook are you using to make the call to `wmv_sidebars()`? the best hook that you should use to register a sidebar is `widget_init'. please, tell me if get stuck

Comment: that is indeed what i am using `add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wmw_sidebars' );`

Comment: last chance: put the function that returns the array of sidebars or the code block that you use to get this array inside the hook `add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wmw_sidebars' );`

Comment: @Cptn have you solved this?